How to make a round CSS button with lines of text with different fonts
How to make this button in CSS. I am able to make a circular button button but not able to style second line of text.
Button needs to two lines of text, each styled differently. Also entire area needs to be clickable.
.drs-button{
  min-width: 240px;
  max-width: 240px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 4em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0;
}
.drs-button:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-top:100%;
}

.drs-button:active{
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

HTML:
<button class="drs-button">
  <span class="txt-line1">DRS</span>
  <span class="txt-line2">15 Secs</span>
</button>



body {
  background-color: navy;
}

.drs-button{
  min-width: 240px;
  max-width: 240px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 4em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0;
}
.drs-button:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-top:100%;
}

.drs-button:active{
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
    <button class="drs-button">
      <span class="txt-line1">DRS</span>
      <span class="txt-line2">15 Secs</span>
    </button>





Please turn that code into a runnable snippet =)

Without your (relevant) HTML the CSS is largely meaningless, since we have no idea what you're working with, or whether the selectors in your CSS are correct for the HTML you're working with. Please, share enough ("[mcve]") code that we can reproduce your problem.

The method of making the button circular doesn't work for me (there's a mixture of px and em units). Without a runnable reproducible example we cannot help you properly - any answer will just be a guess. When you give us the HTML please let us know whether you are allowed to alter it or not.

Thank you for adding the HTML - but the code given still does nor produce a circular button.

Buttons are allowed to contain phrasing content, which includes inline child elements such as <span>.
So, simply wrap the two parts of your button content in <span> elements.
<button class="drs-button">
  <span>Line One</span>
  <span>Line Two</span>
</button>

Then you can style each span differently, as illustrated in this snippet.


body {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.drs-button {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.drs-button:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.drs-button span {
  display: block;
}

.drs-button span:last-child {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #dd0000;
}
<button class="drs-button">
  <span>Line One</span>
  <span>Line Two</span>
</button>




Another way to do it without aspect ratio and last-child pseudo elements.


body {
  background: navy;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.btn-drs {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  padding: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.btn-drs:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn-drs span.txt-primary,
.btn-drs span.txt-secondary{
  display: block;
}

.btn-drs span.txt-secondary {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #dd0000;
}

.btn-drs:hover span.txt-secondary {
  color: #EEF;
}
<button class="btn-drs">
  <span class="txt-primary">Line One</span>
  <span class="txt-secondary">Line Two</span>
</button>




Why would you want to avoid using aspect-ratio or the :last-child pseudo element?

It is just another way.
